# Creating a function that executes lambda functions. Do I have to deal with void vs non void separately?

Tags: c++, templates

I had this simple function:

```
template <class F>
F lockAndDo(F &&fct)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
    return fct();
}
```

For which I could pass lambda functions like this:

```
int value = LockAndDo([&] {
        return _collection.size();
    });
```

The problem is that sometimes I needed to pass a void lambda function, and the compiler would brag about me trying to return from a void lambda function.

I then had to do this separation for void and not void lambda functions

```
template <class F>
F lockAndDoAndReturn(F &&fct)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
    return fct();

}
template <class F>
void lockAndDo(F &&fct)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
    fct();
}
```

Is there a better approach that I can use to create just one function, not two, that do the same thing?

Comment: F is the type of the (lambda) function object itself, not of what it returns, so it is wrong regardless of whether it returns void or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need a recent enough version of C++, which I hope is common practice.

I think you have multiple choice, depending on the behavior you want.

If you want to return by value, use `auto` as your return type:

```
template <class F>
auto lockAndDo(F &&fct)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
    return std::invoke(fct);
}
```

If you allow to return references, this doesn't work, and you'll need `decltype(auto)` instead.

```
template <class F>
decltype(auto) lockAndDo(F &&fct)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
    return std::invoke(fct);
}
```

Keep in mind that you now still require void functions. This can be solved as well:

```
template <class F, class ...A>
decltype(auto) lockAndDo(F &&fct, A &&...a)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
    return std::invoke(fct, std::forward<A>(a)...);
}
```

And as you might have noticed, I've used `std::invoke` in all the examples as it supports all kind of invokables. This includes pointers to member functions ...

Left to the reader: you can make your function conditionally noexcept if you care about it.

Comment: Why wouldn't `auto` work with references? Is there a reason behind this choice?

Comment: It uses value semantics. `auto &` would give references, though it would than introduce problems with return by value from the func

Comment: What are 'value semantics'? I want to study the reasons behind this

Answer (score 4):

You can make the return type [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (or `decltype(auto)`, depending on the scenarios. Refer to the linked page for more), which will be determined by the return statement.

> `(since C++14)` in the return type of a function or lambda expression: `auto& f();`. The return type is deduced from the operand of its `non-discarded (since C++17)` return statement.

e.g.

```
template <class F>
auto // determined by the return type of `F`, including `void`
lockAndDo(F &&fct)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
    return fct();
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3b98rZ2f18HSEmDH)

Comment: "Effective Modern C++" item 3 says why `auto` is discouraged when used as function return type.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I only remembered that he said `decltype(auto)` should be used instead of `auto` for some cases.. Is it that?

Comment: Yes. `auto` ignores reference-ness of the returned value, while `decltype(auto)` won't.